# Whole blazor web app stop working when exception occured

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

Please advice me any suitable solution for the following issue,

when the blazor application throws any exception, the whole application goes down and no link is working, until I can run the application through studio again.

what to do with this issue?

thanks & best regards

## **Edited**

*(In order to provide requested info)*

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create a blazorserverside app:
2. Modify IncrementCount

At `Counter.razor`:

```
void IncrementCount()
{
    currentCount += 1;
    _ = 0 / (5-currentCount);  // <-- force error when currentCount is 5.
}
```

3. Push `Click Me` button for 5 times to raise error.
4. Try to navigate to other app pages (Home, Fetch Data) nothing happens because it fails silently on client.

**Additional info**

On `Startup.cs` errors are configured:

```
app.UseExceptionHandler("/errors");
```

The stack trace errors:

```
Unhandled exception rendering component: Attempted to divide by zero.
System.DivideByZeroException: Attempted to divide by zero.
   at blaex.Pages.Counter.IncrementCount() in /home/dani/tmp/blaex/Pages/Counter.razor:line 27
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.EventCallbackWorkItem.InvokeAsync[T](MulticastDelegate delegate, T arg)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.IHandleEvent.HandleEventAsync(EventCallbackWorkItem callback, Object arg)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.Renderer.DispatchEventAsync(Int32 eventHandlerId, UIEventArgs eventArgs)
```

Comment: Handle your exceptions. Always a good idea. I'm not sure but the current Blazor behaviour could be by design.

Comment: Please provide code or some stack trace / logs. At which part of the application are the exceptions occurring?

Comment: I think that it is a good question. I append additional info to make it SO friendly.

Comment: .net Core 6 will have an ErrorBoundary component that might be useful: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/asp-net-core-updates-in-net-6-preview-4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edited Jul'2021**

Fortunately, we now have official literature in this regard: [Handle errors in ASP.NET Core Blazor apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/handle-errors?view=aspnetcore-5.0&pivots=webassembly)
:

> When a Blazor app isn't functioning properly during development, receiving detailed error information from the app assists in troubleshooting and fixing the issue. When an error occurs, Blazor apps display a light yellow bar at the bottom of the screen:
>
> - During development, the bar directs you to the browser console, where you can see the exception.
> - In production, the bar notifies the user that an error has occurred and recommends refreshing the browser.
>
> The UI for this error handling experience is part of the Blazor project templates.

On docs they are Blazor Server detailed circuit errors and, Global exception handling, Log errors with a persistent provider, Places where errors may occur, Advanced scenarios and Additional resources.

Also, I write here some samples about how to catch exceptions:

#### Sample 1:

For your code:

```
void IncrementCount()
{
    currentCount += 1;
    _ = 0 / (5-currentCount);  // <-- force error when currentCount is 5.
}
```

Solution is:

```
void IncrementCount()
{
    currentCount += 1;
    try
    {
        _ = 0 / (5-currentCount);
    }
    catch (DivideByZeroException e)
    {
        // handling exception
    }
}
```

#### Sample 2:

For `DivideByZeroException` on `.razor` page:

```
<h1> @( (0 / (5-currentCount) ).ToString()  ) </h1>
```

They are not solution at this time.

**Edited** work around by [Mister Magoo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2658697/mister-magoo): *There is a solution for Sample 2: `try..catch` - but it's not very practical to do that to all your markup*

```
<h1>
    @try
    {
        @:@((0 / (5 - currentCount)).ToString())
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        @:@ex.Message;
    }
</h1>
```

Comment: There is a solution for Sample 2: try..catch https://blazorfiddle.com/s/qdjir8f4  - but it's not very practical to do that to all your markup - we do need something in the Blazor internals to expose better error handling

Comment: @Mister Magoo - Yeah its good to see the Blazor team realizes this need, however, I wont be surprised if they can't ship anything in the next release. Perhaps 'the community' may need to create a NuGet package to address this?

Comment: hi @csharpdudeni77, I fixed the answer. Blazor is moving on so fast, thanks about to let me know about deprecated links.

Comment: still trying to figure this out as wel just learning blazor as maui seems to be embrasing it for desktop apps @daniherrera

Comment: I didnt downvote and besides stack has no way of telling u who downvoted @daniherrera